# How would I pass in authtoken in my browser get Requests

Tags: python, flask

How would I make following requests

```
$ curl -u eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImV4cCI6MTM4NTY2OTY1NSwiaWF0IjoxMzg1NjY5MDU1fQ.eyJpZCI6MX0.XbOEFJkhjHJ5uRINh2JA1BPzXjSohKYDRT472wGOvjc:unused -i -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/resource
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
```

Work on my python-get requests without having to use my login information but just my auth token like how I made it working on curl?

I tried the following code it throws me `unauthorized access`

```
response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/resource', headers={'Authorization':'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImV4cCI6MTQ3Nzc3MTE2MiwiaWF0IjoxNDc3NzcwNTYyfQ.eyJpZCI6MX0.3IbZmxhDXxymOzXBKnv-rbMDBV_nFYaf-IWIW5YBnWE:unused'})
print response.text
```

Comment: An auth token is usually attached as a header.

Comment: @jpmc26 Ohh as what key? Could you give me an example of the header with the provided auth token in the thread. Thanks!

Comment: No, I can't provide an example. This isn't something I've had the chance to do personally yet, but I believe it depends on what header name the server is coded to accept.

Comment: You might find [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/restful-authentication-with-flask) helpful.

Comment: @jpmc26 That's exactly the tutorial I'm following with. I updated my thread and made it more on the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the curl manpage:

> ```
> -u, --user <user:password>
>     Specify the user name and password to use for server authentication.
> ```

In the requests documentation [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/):

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

So the following might work (untested):

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/resource', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImV4cCI6MTQ3Nzc3MTE2MiwiaWF0IjoxNDc3NzcwNTYyfQ.eyJpZCI6MX0.3IbZmxhDXxymOzXBKnv-rbMDBV_nFYaf-IWIW5YBnWE','unused')
print response.text
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do basic auth but with no password (`unused`)

Try this:

```
response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/resource', auth=('eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImV4cCI6MTM4NTY2OTY1NSwiaWF0IjoxMzg1NjY5MDU1fQ.eyJpZCI6MX0.XbOEFJkhjHJ5uRINh2JA1BPzXjSohKYDRT472wGOvjc', 'unused'))

print(response.text)
```